# Generate unique string in Github Actions

Tags: unique, github-actions

I have the following `env` definition for a job in Github Actions:

```yaml
jobs:
  build-test-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      FOO : foobar-${{ github.sha }}
      BAR : BAZ
```

However the `github.sha` remains identical when the same workflow is re-run without any commit in between. I need the `FOO` to be unique for every run (even if it's technically a re-run), independently of commits.

Two options I'm thinking of:

- either generate a random string
- or get the current unix timestamp

I don't know how to get either of these values in the context of the `env:` directive. There are some actions available to use within `steps` but how is it possible to get this kind of unique values right from the `env` directive instead?

Comment: From what I can tell, you can't get a date from standard GitHub Action contexts, so I don't think there's an easy way to do that other than you below solution. Note that `run_id` and `run_number` are also not unique even with a re-run.

Answer (score 14):

There is a `github.run_attempt` variable now (not sure since when) that increments on re-runs. So by combing that with e.g. `github.run_id` you can generate per-run fully unique strings.

```yaml
jobs:
  build-test-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      FOO : foobar-${{ github.run_id }}-${{ github.run_attempt }}
      BAR : BAZ
```

Make sure to put a delimiter inbetween (`-` in the example above) as you might get duplicates otherwise. Without it, e.g. `123` could result from both `run 12 attempt 3` or `run 1 attempt 23`.

Quick [link to the relevant docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) for further reading.

Answer (score 4):

```yaml
jobs:
  build-test-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      BAR : BAZ

    steps:
      - name: generate FOO unique variable based on timestamp
        run: echo FOO=foobar--$(date +%s) >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: other step that needs FOO
        run: echo ${{ env.FOO }}
```

Comment: You could also use `${RANDOM}${RANDOM}`.  Be careful with env variables: If you add them to `$GITHUB_ENV`, they work, but if you add them as an `export` to `.bashrc`, they will only work in the `run` portion but not in other arguments.  This can be complicate a Windows build.